# Shopify liquid code update to send a different email based on product tag or title

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using the Tax Receipts App within Shopify and was advised by its developer that if I wanted to send a different receipt PDF, I would just need to add liquid code to the top of the Receipt PDF doc (which is just the HTML version of the tax receipt) to tell the app to scan the product tags, determine if the "US" tag is present, then send the correct PDF. I haven't had any luck with product tags (assuming bc "contains" doesn't search a text string, but total rookie here), so I tried to revise the code to search product title instead; I know the code is doing SOMETHING because I am getting the test receipt PDFs, but it's still just sending the same version to everyone.

Here's the code I've added to the top of the Receipts PDF (in the Tax Receipts App):

```
{% assign contains_us = true %}
    {% for title in product.title %}
      {% if product.title contains "(US)" %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% if contains_us %}
    US RECEIPT
    {% else %}
    CA RECEIPT
    {% endif %}
    {% for title in product.title %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Goal: have it send a different PDF based on whether the title contains "(US)" OR the product is tagged with "US". Any help would be very appreciated :)